# how to migrate tasks from JIRA to TFS 2012

Tags: jira, azure-devops, tfs-migration

I have been searching the Tool(freeware) for a clean solution on how to migrate tasks from JIRA to TFS2012.

Already i try to setup tfs-jira-synchronizer setup 
I've been trying to set this up on a sandbox server however when I ran the installer I didn't get the **acl** application file in my virtual directory. 
 The installer completed without errors.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to migrate from Jira to TFS.

I ended up writing my own utility to do so. I felt this was a good candidate for 'open-sourcing' so have published it on GitHub here:

https://github.com/KilskyreMan/JiraToTfs/releases

(tested against TFS Server 2012, 2013 and 2015)

Utility handles all main and custom templates, links and attachments.

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/KilskyreMan/JiraToTfs/wiki

Hopefully this can be of use to other people in this situation.

Cheers - Ian.

Comment: Great tool! Using it now. One piece of feedback I could give is that it reverses order of tickets where latest ticket in Jira becomes the first ticket in TFS. Not sure if this is by design or not. Thanks

Comment: Glad it was of use LukeP. Will certainly look into the ordering of tickets (which was'nt intentional :)).

Answer (score 1):

Try the integration platform.
http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

It's buggy, hard to work with, and usually really annoying but it is your best bet.

Comment: hello  i have .net framework4 when iam installing tfsintegration tool it geting error  .netframework3.5 error  please give me suggestion how to install and what is steps for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.spartez.jira.plugins.bork.tfs4jira
for synchronizing the two systems

If you want a one-time migration of data, I don't know of a free tool for that. I'd probably start with looking at the data formats that TFS will accept, then write a tool that parses an XML backup from JIRA to create a file in a suitable format for import. You could even use the JIRA REST API to get the data but that might be slower depending on how much data you want to export from JIRA

Disclosure: at ServiceRocket we do many data migrations into JIRA each year.

Comment: hello Mdoar, i can setup the tfs4jira synchronizer successfully for that we need to install IIS now i can access tfs4jira web page but when iam giving the jira weburl then iam geting error like The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. how can i fix it ?

Comment: @mdoar , Can help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867638/how-do-i-find-synchronizer-external-url-for-tfs4jira-on-visualstudio-com , faced problem with initial configuration(i'm new, work with tfs )

Comment: Best to contact the add-on vendor