# How do I find Synchronizer External URL for TFS4JIRA on visualstudio.com

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, jira, jira-plugin, azure-devops

I need to configure TFS4JIRA with visualstudio.com but On TFS4JIRA plugins in JIRA asking 'Synchronizer External URL' and I tried to find URL on visualstudio.com but didn't get it.

Answer (score 2):

'Synchronizer External URL' is the address of Synchronizer application that should be installed on your Windows machine, it has nothing to do with xxx.visualstudio.com. Remember that Synchronizer address should be accessible from internet, or more precise - from http://tfs4jira-ondemand.spartez.com (please refer to this documentation: https://confluence.spartez.com/display/TFS4JIRA/Required+network+configuration).

Answer (score 1):

If TFS4JIRA wants a project url then it'll be:

https://ACCOUNTNAME.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/PROJECTNAME

If it wants a collection url then it's just:

https://ACCOUNTNAME.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection

Comment: I used second URL, but not work on "TFS4JIRA Synchronizer Connection Setup" page. password which i used?

Comment: Have you enabled alternate credentials for the account that TFS4JIRA is going to use to connect to VSTS/VSO https://confluence.spartez.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=8781995

Comment: No, I'm using professional user credential for  TFS4JIRA, Does need to account credential or  professional user ?

Comment: You need user credentials for VSTS and they must be set up as alternate creds.  I don't understand where you are in the setup process but it really isn't very involved.  Maybe these will help http://samirvaidya.blogspot.co.uk/2015/09/installing-and-configuring-tfs4jira.html and https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/160156/where-do-i-define-a-tfs-repository-connection-for-tfs4jira

Comment: Thanks Let I find same.