# Transfer issues from JIRA to Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: jira, azure-devops

Has anyone had any experience migrating JIRA tickets to Team Services? I'm just looking to see if there are any products or easy methods to help with the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for a (1 time) migration instead of synchronization, and you have experience with REST APIs and scripting, then writing your own scripts/tool might be an "easy" solution, especially if you need to map different project/field configurations.

There are some related questions here:

- [how to migrate tasks from JIRA to TFS 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17984759/how-to-migrate-tasks-from-jira-to-tfs-2012)
- [How can I migrate a JIRA project to Team Foundation Work Item Tracking (TFS WIT)?](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/52740/how-can-i-migrate-a-jira-project-to-team-foundation-work-item-tracking-tfs-wit)

Relevant REST API documentation is available here:

- [VS Team Services & TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/overview)
- [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/cloud/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [TFS4JIRA](https://confluence.spartez.com/display/TFS4JIRA/About+TFS4JIRA) which support "TFS / VSTS to-and-from JIRA issues synchronization".

> if the JIRA issue isn't yet paired with any TFS / VSTS work item
>   create a new TFS / VSTS work item copy values of the fields for which
>   mappings are configured from the issue to the work item pair the issue
>   with newly created work item